# ArcGIS Online trouble with 3D extrusion in ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-online, arcscene

I'm having difficulty viewing my Feature Class in Scene Viewer where my saved symbology is not appearing as 3D Extruded, but rather as 2D.  I have a Feature Class uploaded to my ArcGIS Online account and opened it in Map Viewer.  Here, I was able to apply my desired symbology and save.  When I view this Feature Class in Scene Viewer, by symbology is correct, but I cannot view it as 3D Extruded.  If I change the Symbols option from "Original Symbols" to "Change Symbols", I'm able to view my data in 3D, however I lose my symbology.

How can I keep my symbology and view it as 3D in Scene Viewer?

Here are a couple screen captures to help illustrate my issue.

**Correct symbology, not in 3D**
[image]

**3D, but cannot change symbology**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is a known limitation. If you have the symbology on the polygons, you can extrude the features and convert the dataset into multipatch in ArcGIS Pro using Layer 3D to Feature Class tool. Then you can create a scene layer package and upload that to ArcGIS Online and use the scene layer and style it further in SV or you can upload the multipatch feature class in a zipped GDB to AGOL and from the published feature layer you can publish a scene layer.

Comment: Answered through GeoNet - https://geonet.esri.com/message/701139-arcgis-online-trouble-with-3d-extrusion-in-arcscene